# can I call requestAction from within a requestAction chunk in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a bunch of independent controller actions, which I need to cascade in a single page. For that I was thinking of making a requestAction call within a requestAction. The second call fails everytime with a 404. I am new to cakephp and am not sure whether if it is even possible.

Is there a better way using jQuery which can help me achieve this.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| header                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                |
|+---------------------------------------------+ +--------------+|
|| Submenu                                     | | Main Menu    ||
|+---------------------------------------------+ |              ||
|                                                +--------------+|
|+---------------------------------------------+                 |
|| Content View                                |                 |
||                                             |                 |
|+---------------------------------------------+                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so when an option from main menu is selected submenu is displayed using requestAction, then I want the first menu item of the submenu be selected by default, which should display the ContentView associated with that menu option. I am using second requestAction call for that.

Comment: Using requestAction is not recommended. I did the same mistake when I started out in cakePHP, there's usually a better way to do it. I'm curious as to how you're using requestAction when the user selects the menu on the client side. Could you give more info?

Comment: Oh! may bad. requestAction is for the firstRendering of the page. For subsequent Actions I use Ajax based requests. My problem is rendering the page for the first time. Subsequently i am good. 

So what i want is that when user selects an option from main menu, i load the submenu using ajax. As part of that I want to also load content view. I am also ok to load it using ajax. But dont know how to do it.

Comment: Why not use ajax for all? You're essentially talking about menu/content that is loaded when the user clicks the menu item right? Why not send multiple ajax requests?

Comment: Thats what I dont know how to do it in cake, using CakePHP and hence I thought of Using request Action. :)

Comment: Have a look at this set of links : http://ahsanity.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/get-started-with-ajax-in-cakephp/ Or just look at a jquery tutorial and dig in! :)

Answer (score 1):

In this , You should use Ajax.Its better than reuestAction.